# Python | simple if/else statement inside for loop - not working

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I've just started learning Python. After getting myself comfortable with Bash, I've decided to use Python and learn it. Please don't throw flame if this question seems stupid.

I got this "file.txt" which contains:

```
81
99
90
90
70
100
```

The if/else statement I'm using inside for loop does not seem to work:

```
with open('file.txt') as x:  
    for num in x:
        if num  >  90 :
            print "NOT ok - ",num
        else :
            print "Okay - ",num
```

I can't understand why the output would be "NOT ok" for all the numbers.

```
NOT ok -  81

NOT ok -  99

NOT ok -  90

NOT ok -  90

NOT ok -  70

NOT ok -  100
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: replace num with int(num) in if statement. You are comparing string with number.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing string with number in `if` part.

Replace `num` with `int(num)` in `if` part.

```
>>> '81' > 90
True
>>> 81 > 90
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dinesh pointed out, when reading from a file, the num is currently of string type. You can test the same by typing in the following:

```
for num in x:
    print type(num)   
    if num  >  90 :
```

So, before comparing the num, type it as below:

```
if int(num) > 90:
```